# Getting error while clicking on edit function button in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to edit by data from database via my admin panel. So i created table with clickable button for edit function.
[image: Picture of Admin panel with Edit button]

Now when I click on edit button, I am seeing ID number at bottom but getting sorry page couldn't found error ! I have double checked all controller, route and everything. It seems all good, but I don't know what's the error!

Route Code:

```
 Route::get('/admin/baseFare',[
 'uses' => 'ExtraBaseFareController@basefare',
 'as' => 'base.fare'
 ]);

 Route::get('/admin/baseFare/edit/{$id}',[
 'uses' => 'ExtraBaseFareController@editBaseFare',
 'as' => 'editbase.fare'
 ]);

 Route::post('/admin/baseFare/update/{id}', [
 'uses' => 'ExtraBaseFareController@baseFareUpdate',
 'as' => 'base.fareupdate'
 ]);`
```

Controller Code:

```
public function basefare()
{
    $base = BaseFare::all();
    return view('Admin.BaseFare.index')->With('base', $base);

}

public function editBaseFare($id)
{
    $base = BaseFare::find($id);

    return view('Admin.BaseFare.editBaseFare')->with('base', $base);

}

public function baseFareUpdate(Request $request, $id) 
{

    $base = BaseFare::find($id);

    $base->fareinpercentage = $request->fareinpercentage;

    $base->fareinrupees = $request->fareinrupees;

    $base->save();

    Session::flash('success','Base fare successfully updated');

    return redirect()->route('base.fare');

}
```

Index Page code:

```
 <table class="table display nowrap table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-3 scroll-horizontal">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>S.No</th>
                                        <th>Fare in Percentage (%)</th>
                                        <th>Fare in Rupees (Rs)</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    @php $number = 1; @endphp
                                    @foreach($base as $base)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                {{ $number.'.' }}
                                                @php $number++; @endphp
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{ $base->fareinpercentage }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $base->fareinrupees }}</td>
                                            <td> 
                                            <a href="{{ route('editbase.fare',['id' => $base->basefareid ]) }}" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Edit ">
                                                <i class="la la-edit"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>`
```

Edit Page Code:

```
 <form class="form" method="post" action="{{ route('base.fareupdate',['id' => $base->basefareid ]) }}">
                                    <div class="form-body">
                                        <h4 class="form-section"><i class="la la-eye"></i>Base Fare Controller</h4>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="userinput2">Fare in Percentage (%)</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="fareinpercentage"  value="{{ $base->fareinpercentage }}" class="form-control border-primary" name="fareinpercentage">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="userinput3">Fare in Rupee (Rs)</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="fareinrupees" value="{{ $base->fareinrupees }}" class="form-control border-primary" name="fareinrupees">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-actions right">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mr-1">
                                            <i class="ft-x"></i> Cancel
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            <i class="la la-check-square-o"></i> Save
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>`
```

These are the codes, the kindly help me to find our the error, The main function is to edit the field from database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you can't go to the edit page.
Run 'php artisan route:list' and compare the routes.
And I can't figure out why you have dollar sign before the id in the route.

Comment: the dollar sign is the problem ! when cleared, magic happend !